# Data from PlaceAutoCompleteAPI not getting Inflated into Views

Tags: android, google-places-api

So, I have been trying to get place id from PlaceAutoComplete Fragment and pass it to another activity. The other activity is supposed to get the place id and inflate the views by getting all the necessary information from Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById() method.

Here is the class where the PlaceAutoComplete Fragment is stored:

```
public class PlaceSearch extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_place_search);

    //Hiding SupportActionBar
    try {
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //PlaceAutoComplete Search Implementation
    PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);


    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            Log.i(String.valueOf(this), "Place: " + place.getName() + "\nID: " + place.getId());
            String placeId = place.getId();
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(PlaceSearch.this, PlaceDetailsFromSearch.class);
                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                extras.putString("placeID", placeId);
                intent.putExtras(extras);
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            Log.i(String.valueOf(this), "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });
}}
```

And here is the class where I am trying to inflate the data:

```
public class PlaceDetailsFromSearch extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

String placeId, placeName, placeAddress, placeContact;
String placeWeblink;
float placeRating;
//Views References
RatingBar ratingBar;
TextView tv_place_name, tv_address, tv_call_info, tv_website_info;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_place_details_search);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        placeId = extras.getString("placeId");
    }

    //views
    tv_place_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_place_name_pd);
    tv_address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_address);
    tv_call_info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_call_info);
    tv_website_info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_website_info);
    ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.rb_rating);

    //Google API Client
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();

    loadData();
}

private void loadData() {
    Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull PlaceBuffer places) {
                    if (places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        final Place myPlace = places.get(0);
                        Log.i(String.valueOf(PlaceDetailsFromSearch.this),
                                "Place found: " + myPlace.getName() + "\n Address: " + myPlace.getAddress());
                        placeName = (String) myPlace.getName();
                        tv_place_name.setText(placeName);
                        placeAddress = (String) myPlace.getAddress();
                        tv_address.setText(placeAddress);
                        placeContact = (String) myPlace.getPhoneNumber();
                        tv_call_info.setText(placeContact);
                        placeRating = myPlace.getRating();
                        placeWeblink = String.valueOf(myPlace.getWebsiteUri());
                        tv_website_info.setText(placeWeblink);
                        placeRating = myPlace.getRating();
                        ratingBar.setRating(placeRating);

                    } else {
                        Log.i(String.valueOf(PlaceDetailsFromSearch.this), String.valueOf(places.getStatus()));
                    }
                    places.release();
                }
            });
}}
```

And this gives me an error with not much information about which String is null.

> E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
>                                                                                at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1688)
>                                                                                at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1637)
>                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.location.places.internal.zzj$zza$zza.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.location.places.internal.zzh.zza(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace it

> placeId = extras.getString("placeId");

by

> placeId = extras.getString("placeID");

in **onCreate()** method of **PlaceDetailsFromSearch.java** activity. Hope your problem will be solved. Because you are passing **placeID** as an extra from **PLaceSearch.java** activity.

Comment: I was losing my head over this !!! and the error was because of case sensitivness

Comment: @GautamHans sometime it happens. :)

Comment: Pleasure is mine. Thanks. :)